# Implement multiple AJAX-requested series via HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I want to plot the performance results I collected to HighCharts via AJAX.
Somehow, the .addSeries API call does not work properly.
Can someone analyze, if I'm on the right track?

```
$(function () {
    $('#chart3').highcharts({
        chart: {
            //type: 'scatter'
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Performance Results',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Update 7',
            x: -20
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['1.270', '1.272', '1.273', '1.274', '1.276', '1.278', '1.280', '1.284', '1.286', '1.288', '1.290', '1.292', '1.294', '1.296', '1.298', '1.300', '1.302', '1.304', '1.306'],
            labels: {
                rotation: -60,
                style: {
                    fontSize:'13px'
                }
            }
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Miliseconds (ms)'
            }
        },
        /*
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        */
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [
        {
            regression: true,
            regressionSettings: {
                type: 'linear',
                color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .9)'
            },
            name: 'Punkte',
            color: 'rgba(17, 201, 176, .5)',
            data: [
                [1, 125373],
                [2, 125161],
                [3, 124497],
                [4, 124640],
                [5, 124914],
                [6, 124284],
                [7, 125039],

            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Download Files',
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5224, 5529, 5520, 5928, 6604, 7205, 7155, 5505, 4843, 6769, 0, 0, 0],

        },       
        {
            name: 'Install Applications',
            data: [85859, 83681, 82710, 82337, 0, 83974, 82786, 79072, 78337, 65434, 67769, 59147, 57979, 58465, 56288, 56773, 56359, 56512, 56883]
        }
        ]
    });


    var x;
    var y;

    var chart = $('#chart3').highcharts();

    $.getJSON("http://performance/ajax.php?action=x", function(xdata)
    {
        chart.addSeries({
            data: xdata;
        });
    });

    $.getJSON("http://performance/ajax.php?action=y", function(ydata)
    {
        chart.addSeries({
            data: ydata;
        });
    });
});
```

The ydata and xdata part at the bottom is the function I wrote to add the series.

Answer (score 0):

In :96 I used a semicolon, which was syntacticly wrong. Done.